# i am getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found." in APPIUM , i want to verify toast

Tags: appium

this is my error log:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

```
at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:288)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:427)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:179)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:569)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:544)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at Auto_Email.TC_10_DeleteEmail.OCR(TC_10_DeleteEmail.java:187)
at Auto_Email.TC_10_DeleteEmail.deleteEmail(TC_10_DeleteEmail.java:147)
at Auto_Email.TC_10_DeleteEmail.DeleteMail(TC_10_DeleteEmail.java:126)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
```

i added all JAR files following:
commons-io-2.5
jai-imageio-core-1.3.1
jna-4.4.0
jna-platform-4.4.0
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.2
lept4j-1.6.0
logback-classic-1.2.3
logback-core-1.2.3
selenium-server-standalone-2.7.0-patched-sources
slf4j-api-1.7.5
tess4j-3.4.0

please someone help me to solve this problem..
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Singh, actually i am running in real android device, and i have libtesseract3051.dll, gsdll64.dll files extracted from tess4j folder. and i have added these 2 dll's to the folder called 'dll' in my root project.

let me know if i am wrong.. still i am getting error.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to not correctly referencing the required dll files in your project setup. For a tess4j project in eclipse, you may add a line to your VM argument in the run configuration, where you have put the dll files in a 'dlls' folder, and keep the folder in the project's root folder, in your eclipse workspace :

-Djna.library.path=${workspace_loc:/name_of_your_project}/dlls

The dll files are gsdll64.dll, liblept168.dll and libtesseract302.dll for a 64 bit runtime. The dll files are already bundled in the tess4j jar in the win32 folder, that you may extract and add to your own dll folder as mentioned above already.

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Singh, actually i am running in real android device, and i have libtesseract3051.dll, gsdll64.dll files extracted from tess4j folder. and i have added these 2 dll's to the folder called 'dll' in my root project.

let me know if i am wrong.. still i am getting error.

Comment: The solution would work on Windows, but for Android, you may want to refer these links : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793531/use-dll-files-in-android-application)  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198909/ocr-for-android-application-tess4j)

Comment: Even i tried same code in normal java project.. even there i m facing same problem.. i m really trying hard but not getting output :-( .. it always says same problem...

Comment: Please check (https://reachmnadeem.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/ocr-with-tess4j) out for a mavenised java project using tess4j. While importing the project, in eclipse use the option for Maven> Existing Maven Projects. There will be a dead repository entry in the pom.xml for jai_imageio-1.1.jar, so just directly reference it in your classpath.

Comment: I am using 64bit Windows, and i haven't tried Maven project... and one more doubt that should i install 64bit tessract ocr.exe?? If yes plz share the link to download 64 bit.. i didn't get it

Comment: set the system variable in your main class as `System.setProperty("jna.library.path","absolute\\path\\to\your\\dll\folder");` and then the rest of code after that. INstallation of tesseract is not needed if you have the required dll saved.